# How to automate restore of veeam backup

Tags: windows, backup, script, restore

we are creating backups with veeam agent for windows.
I would need to restore those backups in an automated fashion. is there any command line client, a way to script the restore process or something similar?
Sadly there is not really any documentation about that particular part...

BR

Comment: View this page, it may help... https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/agentforwindows/configurator/howto_automate.html?ver=40

Comment: thanks for the link - i already knew this page but to my understanding i can only manage configurations with this command - I even found a way to trigger a backup but I can't trigger a restore which is what I need....